# empty input while uploading file with FormData in laravel

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, laravel, file-upload

I'm using laravel 5.2 php5.6 fpm. I have form where I can upload video file. everything works fine if I upload small video, it uploads file and show the rest of inputs, but if I try upload a larger video(4MB for example), the WHOLE input is empty, its just returns `null`. so none of inputs are provided.

my php.ini

```
upload_max_filesize = 200M
post_max_size = 200M
memory_limit = 800M # increased it, just to make sure its not causing the problem
```

I restated server, nginx, php-fpm process, cleared cache, but its the same.
I send the data with js `FormData`

```
$("input.uploaded_photos,input.uploaded_videos").change(function(){
        var input = this;
        var albumId = $("[name='id']").val();
        var albumType = $("[name='type']:checked").val();
        //only continue if currently selected album type matches the current input field

        if($(input).attr('data-type') == albumType){
            if (input.files && input.files.length) {
                var selectedType = $(input).parents('form').find("[name='type']:checked").val();
                var existingUploads = $('.selling-album-upload-' + selectedType + 's-row .selling-album-upload').length;
                var totalResultingUploads = input.files.length + existingUploads;
                var selectedPackCount = parseInt($(input).parents('form').find("[name='picture_pack']").val());
                var dataform = new FormData();
                for(var iFile in input.files){
                    if(!isNaN(iFile)){//otherwise we'll get 'length' and 'file' as keys too
                        var file = input.files[iFile];
                        dataform.append(input.name, file, file.name);
                    }
                }
                dataform.append('album_id', albumId);
                dataform.append('type', albumType);

                $.ajax({
                    url: '/myurl'
                    type: 'POST',
                    data: dataform,
                    async: false,//false, otherwise it creates a GET Request
                    success: function (data) {
                        // do something
                    },
                    cache: false,
                    contentType: false,
                    processData: false
                });
            }
        }
    });
```

if I upload 'large' video `Input::all()` returns null, its blank, I think the problem should be in js. anyway here's php code:

```
public function postAddSellingAlbumUpload(){
    $album_id = Input::get('album_id');
    $type = Input::get('type');
    $existing_uploads = Session::get('agent_selling_uploaded_$type'.'s', []);
    $new_uploads = [];
    $posted_files = Input::file('uploaded_'.$type.'s');


    foreach($posted_files as $posted_file){
        $path = '/uploads/tmp/'.uniqid().'.'.Userimage::guessExtension($posted_file->path());
        File::copy($posted_file->path(), public_path().$path);
        $posted_file_id = uniqid();
        $new_uploads[$posted_file_id] = [
            'id' => $posted_file_id,
            'album_id' => $album_id,
            'type' => $type,
            'path' => $path,
        ];
    }
    Session::put('agent_selling_uploaded_$type'.'s', array_merge($existing_uploads, $new_uploads));

    return response()->json([
        'success' => true,
        'uploads' => $new_uploads,
    ]);
}
```

again, the problem happens only if upload 'large' file. if file is small size, everything's ok. its seem like the problem is about `upload_max_filesize` but I set properly the config file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

finally find out, I have multiple php versions on my OS, one of them(which was running) had `upload_max_filesize = 2M` and `post_max_size = 8M` that was causing the problem